# Is there any DatePicker for twitter-bootstrap 1.4?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I wasn't able to find any date picker in the documentation.  How could such an obvious control be missing? Is there any third party solution to this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is, check out this link:

http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/

The look and feel is good and the usage is simple too.

Comment: Just you guys are aware, I found someone has forked this project with proper bug fixing, better documentation and internationalization support: https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker

Comment: @Kave Thanks for sharing the link! I was still using the original and wondering how to do validation on start dates and end dates, and the link you provided solved my problem!